Rotating a string after mapping through individual characters and increasing space height
Consider the following code that maps through a string and rotates the individual letters. How can I increase the height of the space? (See between MODERN and ART).
I prefer that the user just types a space, not inserting any commands.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\cjk{Sim Sun}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_put_left:Nn\l_tmpa_str{现代术}
\str_put_left:Nn\l_tmpa_str{modern~art}
\cs_new:Npn \l_yl_rotate_letter:n #1{
   \rotatebox{90}{\fbox{\cjk \MakeUppercase{#1}}}
}

\huge\sffamily
\rotatebox{-90}{\str_map_function:cN{l_tmpa_str}\l_yl_rotate_letter:n}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}


add a strut: \rotatebox{90}{\fbox{\cjk \rule{0pt}{10pt}\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

@UlrikeFischer  Thanks I was adding it \str_put_left:Nn\l_tmpa_str{modern~art}. Please type this as an answer so I can accept.

Change the space into a phantom.
You should be not using strings, but token lists.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newfontfamily\cjk{AR PL SungtiL GB}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\boxedverticaltext}{m}
 {
  \yl_bvt:n {#1}
 }

\tl_new:N \l__yl_bvt_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yl_bvt:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__yl_bvt_tl {#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l__yl_bvt_tl { ~ } { {\phantom{A}} }
  \rotatebox{-90}{\tl_map_function:NN \l__yl_bvt_tl \__yl_bvt_letter:n}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yl_bvt_letter:n
 {
  \rotatebox{90}{\fbox{\cjk \text_uppercase:n{#1}}\hspace{-\fboxrule}}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\huge

\boxedverticaltext{modern art现代术}

\end{document}

I don't have Sim Sun, but the font I replaced it with seems to match the desired layout.

Please, note that functions (cs) don't take an l or g prefix. They're preceded by __ if they're not meant to be public. Also, \__yl_bvt_letter:n should be protected, because it performs unexpandable tunctions.
Your \sffamily does nothing.
